# How to get an .exe file to execute no matter where the user types its name in command shell on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, environment-variables

I have Windows 7.

I have a .exe file here:

```
c:\tools\dailybackup.exe
```

When I am in the CMD window, I want to be able to type "dailybackup" **in any directory** and have it execute.

**Do I still need to change the environment variables to do this or does Windows 7 have an easier more user-friendly way to do this now?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You still have to change the PATH environment variable to include `c:\tools\`

Answer (score 4):

To add to Nifle's answer, to add to the PATH *permanently*:

```
setx path "%path%;c:\tools"
```

You need to close and start another CMD prompt to see the changes to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from *ANY* directory, then your only choice, as you've pointed out, is to modify the environment variables and add "`c:\tools`" to your System or current user's $PATH variable.

Comment: On Windows, environment variables are delimited by surrounding percents, i.e. `%PATH%`, not a preceding dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get there from here. The simplest (and safest, depending on your comfort level where editing the registry is involved) is to use a batch file and place it in the \Windows folder. For example, your batch file (named "dailybackup.bat" for consistency), might contain the following:

```
@echo off
pushd
cd /d c:\utils
dailybackup.exe
popd
```

I use this method for a number of commands/processes that I regularly use at the DOS prompt.

Alternatively, you can create an *"alias"* for the executable in the registry. To do this, go to `"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths"`. You'll see a whole lot of sub-keys here. What you want to do is add one for *"dailybackup.exe"*. Right-click on *"App Paths"* and select *"New"* and *"Key"*. Enter the key name (ending with .exe). (This is an opportunity to use a shortened version of the name, if you wish, such as *"dbu.exe"*, for example. Anyway, enter your alias (we'll just go with *"dailybackup.exe"*). Now, in the right-hand pane, double click *"Default"* and enter the full path and name of your executable `"c:\utils\dailybackup.exe"`. That's all there is to it. You're done with the registry. To use the new alias, you can hit `(Windows Key)/R` to get the *"Run"* box and enter your alias. For reasons which escape me, the alias won't work directly from a DOS prompt, but needs to be prefaced with *"start"*, as in:

```
C:\Some\Random\Folder >START dailybackup
```

or, if you opted for a shorter alias:

```
C:\Some\Random\Folder >START dbu
```